# C - Any way to initialize srand multiple times?

Tags: c, random

Is there any way to initialize srand multiple times? I have an specific function to generate random numbers but every time i call it gives the same number. Any way to fix this?

```
int whoatk2() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a;
    a = rand() % 50;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: "I have an specific function". Yeah, so what does it look like? Please show the code. Then we may have some hope of telling you what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: `srand` need only be called once for the entire program execution.

Comment: You don't want to call `srand()` multiple times. Just call it once in your `main()` function.

Comment: I see, but is an alternative method to generate a random number?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? What do you want the alternative to do differently (after you fix the `srand` call)?

Comment: I need an alternative because as you said i can´t call srand more than once.

Comment: But the point is you shouldn't call `srand` more than once. It's not a problem. It's the right way to do it. Remove the `srand` from the function, call `srand` once in `main` then the function with `rand` in it will generate a new random number each time.

Comment: Please explain **why do you think you need to "initialize srand" multiple times**. What is the motivation?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you want a specific sequence, you should be calling `srand` *once,* and with a effectively arbitrary value like `time(NULL)`. This would usually be done when your program starts.

If you call it every time you want a random number, you run the very real risk of initialising the generator with the same value each time (if you're calling it many times per second) and therefore getting the same "random" value each time.

This is the sort of thing you *should* be doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));                 // do this once
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {     // do this many times
        printf("%d\n", rand());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output is shown below, with the left column containing the output for the correct code above, and the right column containing the result of moving the `srand` call to *inside* the loop as you currently have (swapping the two lines that have comments above):

```
 966271109          74846356
1059160369          74846356
1868029595          74846356
 758240870          74846356
1795677958          74846356
 806788680          74846356
1374271653          74846356
1658543317          74846356
1843517305          74846356
1568992484          74846356
```

Answer (score 2):

`srand` is the function to *initialize* the pseudo-random generator with a seed, and `rand` is the function to *get* a random number from the generator...

Answer (score 0):

You get the same *random* number repeatedly because you reinitialize the random number generator with the same seed every time you call `whoatk2`, which happens many times during the same second. The sequence of pseudo-random numbers returned by `rand()` is completely determined by the value passed to `srand()`.

You should call `srand()` just **once** at the beginning of the program, preferably with a value that varies faster than `time(NULL)`. You can use `timespec_get()`, `gettimeofday()` or similar:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef TIME_UTC
void random_initialize(void) {
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    srand(ts.tv_nsec);
}
#else
#include <sys/time.h>
void random_initialize(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    srand(tv.tv_usec);
}
#endif

int whoatk2(void) {
    return rand() % 50;
}

int main() {
    random_initialize();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%d ", whoatk2());
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Running 10 times:

```
36 33 35 31 8 32 1 5 30 23 20 8 5 35 47 10 14 26 34 40
32 49 33 16 28 31 22 6 32 33 45 44 17 32 18 38 8 34 28 38
48 38 35 49 25 18 40 3 38 3 36 46 12 26 21 16 15 48 34 39
49 33 9 28 24 39 4 32 33 9 29 23 10 29 41 24 12 33 35 33
5 40 49 16 22 47 27 15 29 39 35 32 28 23 39 35 19 24 10 0
5 45 33 24 4 28 48 40 32 22 27 45 32 11 35 28 0 37 32 9
36 3 38 16 12 25 14 27 30 31 0 49 41 40 39 5 23 26 40 8
11 9 21 15 34 0 13 47 49 47 33 21 3 42 16 19 32 32 33 15
14 2 27 26 19 15 5 41 32 49 48 31 20 12 39 16 15 19 32 20
3 2 34 32 47 24 34 21 0 28 6 48 44 16 6 46 40 48 20 13
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you were printing the function address rather than calling it and printing the result. Fixed that for you.